# FInd and Replace using Beautiful Soup

Tags: regex, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Trying to replace using beautiful soup and regex.  Soup finds what I need I then turn that into a string and use regex to replace but its not working.  Is there a find and replace using beautiful soup.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(file_data, 'html.parser')
found_data = soup.find(class_='front_page_feature')

found_data = str(found_data)
print(re.sub(found_data, mysql_data,file_data,flags = re.DOTALL))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to replace the text contents of a node you found. Just set the `.string` property with the `mysql_data` to change it:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> file_data = """<p class="front_page_feature">Some data</p><p class="else">Other data</p>"""
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(file_data, 'html.parser')
>>> found_data = soup.find(class_='front_page_feature')
>>> mysql_data = "New Text"
>>> found_data.string = mysql_data
>>> soup
# => <p class="front_page_feature">New Text</p><p class="else">Other data</p>
#                                  ^^^^^^^^
```

You may certainly manipulate the text in any other way, even using a regex then.